# jQuery - Get id of element clicked in parent element

Tags: jquery-selectors

Not sure how else to title this (what I titled it doesn't seem to make too much sense - fix it if you feel the need!).

Anyway, I have a div that has some links and I need to get the id of the link that was clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="firstPage">First Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="prevPage">Prev Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label id="currentPage">2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="nextPage">Next Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="lastPage">Last Page</a>
</div>
```

I tried to do it with this:

```
$('#pagination a').click(function() {
    console.log( $('#pagination a').index(this) );
});
```

The #pagination div is dynamically generated in jQuery, so I also tried:

```
$('#pagination a').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $('#pagination a').index(this) );
});
```

But I didn't get any output in the console when a link was clicked in either case.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of a jQuery event handler, `this` always refers to the element that triggered the event:

```
$('#pagination a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('#pagination a').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```